# Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL on same domain from iframe

Tags: iframe, cross-domain

I have an iframe being loaded into an HTTPS page. I am putting the source as https. However, for some reason the javascript inside which calls the parent to resize is erroring out saying cant access cross domain https://localhost... from http://localhost. Why is it saying http? My iframe src is https and the page is https. Any idea how i can have an https iframe call the parent page which is also on https?

Thanks

Comment: You'll have to quote the markup. (Seriously, what were the odds?) Somewhere along the way you're loading a document from `http` rather than `https`.

Comment: Please post a snippet of the code so we can understand better.

Comment: So i see that when i post in the iframe the response is served http and that is why it is happening. Any idea why the response is http after the iframe is loaded https?

Comment: @ScootaP: Again: **Code/markup is worth a thousand words** We can't help you without a concrete example.

Answer (score 0):

iframe is a sandbox.  The JS should be in the parent and not in the iframe.

Comment: *"I have an iframe being loaded into an HTTPS page."* So the parent is `https`. "*I am putting the source as https."* So the iframe is `https`.

Comment: then how would i control the height of the overlay after each page refresh in the iframe? I need the iframe to trigger the parent to resize.

Comment: @ScootaP: It's perfectly fine for the `iframe` to access the parent, as long as both obey the [SOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). Due respect to him, but Brian's answer is useless *based on the information you've provided so far*. You need to provide more information.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the issue. I  have apache as a webserver and jboss as the appserver. On https pages i was sending traffic to my jboss over http therefore and redirects were being redirected back to http instead of https. I enabled the 8443 on jboss and setup a keystore and now traffic coming in on https goes through apache as https and jboss as https and redirects are fine.